# Back to Top Link with a slow animation (CSS only)

Tags: html, css, header, href, effect

I have a simple

```
<a href="#header">Back to Top</a>
```

and this puts me to the top of the page immediately. But I want it to go to the top of the page slowly with just CSS.

Is this possible?
Thanks in Advance.

Edit:
Okay, for anyone with the same problem. It did it with this JQuery:

```
// #btt is ID of the Back to Top Link
    $("#btt").click(function () {
    //html and body is used because of Browser compatibilit
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: If you can use javascript, there is a really simple library called ScrollTo http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: I am not very confident with JQuery but this looks pretty easy. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't activate actions like scrolling with pure CSS, sorry. You'll need some jQuery in there.

What you CAN do is trick the user in thinking the page has scrolled by moving elements around with CSS on :hover, but that's a really bad practice, and would require much more coding that a simple jQuery function.